# MediaWiki table generation with DB data

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki. I need to create a dynamic table for some articles.

For instance, given a page called "Lupo", I need to query the DB, find the entry using the code "Lupo" (same value as the article title) and generate a table with some data provided by the query resultset.

I'm trying to do this using a parser function:

```
$parser->setFunctionHook('adetail', 'aFunc' );
:
function aFunc($parser, $name) {
    // do the query etc.
}
```

invoking the function in this way:

```
{{adetail:Lupo}}
```

Anyway I don't want to repeat the article title also in the parser function parameter.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are calling this parser function from a template, you can use the magic word FULLPAGENAME: `{{adetail:{{FULLPAGENAME}}}}`. FULLPAGENAME will be substituted for the page name, wherever the template is used. `{{PAGENAME}}` does the same thing, but without the namespace prefix.
- If you always want the parser function to assume the current page, you can access it from your function aFunc [like this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTitle.php#getText.28.29):

  ```
  function aFunc($parser, $params) {
     $title = $parser->getTitle()->getPrefixedText();
     ...
  ```
- If you are looking for a way to create dynamic tables without having to hack together your own extensions, I would recommend having a look at [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki).